# Diseñar interfaz HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs-2.0, bootstrap-4

Tengo una duda a la hora de diseñar una interfaz grafica con la misma estructura que la de esta imagen dos columnas y una caja en su interior.
[image: Imagen1]

Ahora mismo estoy usando por ejemplo un row, con dos div.col-6. pero tengo la duda en el diseño interior de esa caja como se hace con una tabla o por capas?
Estoy usando boostrap4 con el elementro card pero no es exactamente el mismo formato.

Gracias, un saludo.

EDIT01:

Tengo un problema con el tamaño en vertical, por ejemplo si tengo 15 cajas dependiendo de la resolución del monitor hace scroll y necesito que se ajuste al tamaño de la pantalla, ya que es para ponerlo de fondo en un monitor y tiene que mostrar toda la información y no tener scroll.

Estoy probando a meterlo en un div con un tamaño pequeño pero no se ajusta.

Codigo html:

```
<div class="auth-main">
</div>
<div class="manolo">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!--<h5 >Tabla Cerverzas</h5>-->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card text-white  mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-2" src="assets/img/glass.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">El Cabo</h5>
                      <h5>IPA &bull; American &bull; 7% &bull; 60 &bull; 1/2 Pinta: 2€ &bull; Pinta: 4€</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>






    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-center">Evento de publicidad</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-center">Evento de publicidad</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="card mb-1">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">Evento de publicidad</h5>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
```

css:

```
.auth-main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(/assets/img/tigre-cabeza.PNG);
  opacity: 0.3;
   filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-right: 200px;
    background-position: center;

}
.manolo{
  width: auto;
  height: 80%;

}
.card{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #96803E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Futura';
  border-color:#96803E;
border-color:#96803E;
}
```

Añado imagen de como esta ahora, como veis tengo el problema para diferentes resoluciones.

Estoy probando cambiando el height: 80%; pero no cambia nada.

[image: Grande]

[image: Mini]

Comment: Hola, el encabezado de tu pregunta esta mal formulado, no se hace diseño con angular eso se hace como mencionas después es con css en tu caso bootstrap, te aconsejo que uses divs y si puedes coloca el codigo que llevas y como se ve

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un pantallazo de cómo se está viendo en tu pantalla? Lo ideal es que jueges con el heigth y uses vw, que es un tipo de medida dinámica según el tamaño vertical de la ventana.

Comment: Buenas, acabo de subir las dos imágenes de como esta el diseño. Como podéis ver dependiendo del tamaño se ve de una forma diferente estoy probando con el height: pero no cambia, no es responsive